# ChromeDriver Failing At Startup

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting a failure and the following error message when I try to start a Selenium Test.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP        
request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55754 
/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message  
was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred   
on a receive.
Source=WebDriver

 InnerException: 
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   Source=System
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   InnerException: 
        HResult=-2146232800
        Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        Source=System
        StackTrace:
             at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
             at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
             at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
        InnerException: 
             ErrorCode=10054
             HResult=-2147467259
             Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
             NativeErrorCode=10054
             Source=System
             StackTrace:
                  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
                  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
             InnerException:
```

Here is the failing code, it has been working fine for months.

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            //ChromeDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SeleniumDrivers", options);
            ////Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
            Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: I did an uninstall of all my WebDriver related nuget packages, and then reinstalled them.  This seems to have solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the ChromeDriver and WebDriver nuget packages and then reinstall them.